# Receive date ranges from JSON file and store them into variables in a JS file?

Tags: javascript, json, date

I am having trouble figuring out how it would be possible to receive dates from a JSON file and have them be requested from a JS file and have them be stored into variables?

This is currently how my .json file looks like:

```
[{
"start": "2018-02-01T00:00:01.235-0600",
"end": "2018-02-28T00:00:01.235-0600"
}]
```

My goal is to be able to work with these two dates from the JSON file to be able to run code during a certain date range.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: are you using node or are we talking browser side?

Comment: I am trying to do this on the browser side.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy actually. First of all, you have to load your Json file. Since you said in the comments that you are doing this on the browser side, I think you can do it synchronously.

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest() // create an xhr request
 xhr.open("GET", "dates.json", false) // open dates.json for getting values - asynchronously = false
xhr.send() // send the request
var response = xhr.responseText // a string containing your Json code
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(response) // save json as an object
// now you have your dates saved as
jsonObj[0].start; 
jsonObj[0].end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your browser can run ES6, then you can solve this using fetch and asynchronous promises:

```
fetch('https://www.server.com/file.json')
  .then(res => {
    if(res.ok) {
        return res.json();  
    }

    throw new Error(`${res.status}:${res.statusText}`);
   })
  .then(dates => dates.map(date => ({ start: new Date(date.start), end: new Date(date.end)}))
  .then(dates => {
        console.log(dates)
   })
  .catch(err => { /*handle errors*/ });
```